# WSO2 Carbon health checks

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I wonder if WSO2 Carbon (my organization uses WSO2 AM 1.10.0) provides a way of health checking and Metrics exporting, which should behaviour like Spring Boot Actuator.

Thanks,
Bo